# How to check radio button in many div of form?

Tags: html

I have a form has many multiple choice questions. Each question is a div. Code below and demo at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuhcev3h/)

```
<form id="doExam" name="DoExam">
    <div>
       <p><b>Question 1:</b>question 1</p>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A">Answer A<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B">Answer B<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C">Answer C<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D">Answer D<br>
    </div>

    <div>
       <p><b>Question 2:</b>question 2</p>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A">Answer A<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B">Answer B<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C">Answer C<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D">Answer D<br>
    </div>

    <div>
       <p><b>Question 3:</b>question 3</p>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A">Answer A<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B">Answer B<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C">Answer C<br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D">Answer D<br>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I check a radio button in 1 div. It works fine, but when I check a radio button in another div, the radio button of the div I did before will be lose. How can I fix it?

Comment: you should really use [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) instead of a plain `div`, that's what it's for

Comment: As The `name` setting tells which group of radio buttons the field belongs to. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.So you need to different names in different divs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a unique name for each set of radio buttons.

```
<form id="doExam" name="DoExam">
  <div>
    <p><b>Question 1:</b>question 1</p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A">Answer A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B">Answer B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C">Answer C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D">Answer D<br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p><b>Question 2:</b>question 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="A">Answer A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="B">Answer B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="C">Answer C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="D">Answer D<br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p><b>Question 3:</b>question 3</p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="A">Answer A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="B">Answer B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="C">Answer C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="D">Answer D<br>
  </div>
</form>
```

See updated Fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/cuhcev3h/1/

Comment: Think of the `name` attribute as the radio button **group**. Any radio button in the same group will take the selection from any other radio button in the same group.

Comment: But how can I assign unique name when create exam by for loop in jsp?

Comment: Without seeing your JSP, use the same logic you use to increment the Question numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the radiobuttons a different name per question

```
<form id="doExam" name="DoExam">
      <div>
        <p><b>Question 1:</b>question 1</p>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Answer A<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Answer B<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Answer C<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">Answer D<br>
      </div>

  <div>
    <p><b>Question 2:</b>question 2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">Answer A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">Answer B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">Answer C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">Answer D<br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p><b>Question 3:</b>question 3</p>
    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="A">Answer A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="B">Answer B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="C">Answer C<br>
    <input type="radio" name="question3" value="D">Answer D<br>
  </div>
</form>
```